# "Kinematic" dynamics or dynamics that ape kinematic movement

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, kinematics, rotational-dynamics, rotational-kinematics

This is a question related to ***unity's* physx engine**, but also a **general** question as well.

How do you make linear and rotational dynamics work kinematicaly? For example, I add a force to an object and it moves forward. Is there a way/formula that you can add opposite forces so that the object can continue to move but can accelerate beyond the plugged-in force?

(ex. force is 15 the object will accelerate 15n each time-frame but, it will not gain any more speed and it's velocity maintains to 15 newtons, also the force is non-constant, so lets say the force changes to 18 (linearly so it will "scale up" from 15 to 18 like 15.1, 15.2, etc. *like the input from a joystick on a controller*) The velocity will increase following dynamic laws and remain at 18, also if force is 0 the object instantly stops).

also, please note That I am **NOT** looking for a PID, I would like a direct approach please. thank you

Comment: Neither velocity nor acceleration can be measured in newtons. Additionally, zero force does not mean the object comes to a stop.

Comment: My question was is there a way to add an opposite force that would bring a moving object to a complete stop

Comment: "force is 15 the object will accelerate 15 N each time-frame but, it will not gain any more speed"  --- In general, this is not what happens.

Comment: Right, with REAL physics, but unity has some wacky rules regarding how physics is added (all computer simulations do due to how they handle time) [link](https://answers.unity.com/questions/696068/difference-between-forcemodeforceaccelerationimpul.html)(see here for an explanation to unity's physics) so force is added each "second".

Comment: Are you asking something like this: "given the force and velocity of a body at a timestep, is it possible to determine the force required to bring the body to a halt?"?

Comment: @NiharKarve yes, a complete halt